# Class not found on tomcat:run

Tags: tomcat, maven-3, jndi

i send emails via jndi (java:/comp/env/mail/Session).

Everything works great if i start the downloaded tomcat with the mail-1.4.4.jar in tomcat/lib-folder, but if i like to start the server via

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

it sais: CNFE: javax.mail.Address

Ok, i am not sure now, i thought the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

must deploy the mail-1.4.4.jar into the tomcat/lib folder (because of the provided). But there it isnt.

Answer (score -1):

The provided means that the dependency is provided by the target environment. This means you need to transport this however into the environment in this case into the tomcat environment into the lib folder. You can try to remove the provided scope and try if it's working.